# Difference between "." and ":" in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In some calling of function we use "." operator while in some we use ":" what is the difference between them.
Example:`storyboard:addEventLsitener(something,something)
graphics.newImageSheet(something,something)`

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua

Comment: This is a duplicate, please close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo:bar(...)` is syntactic sugar for `foo.bar(foo, ...)`, i. e. that's the "traditional" object-oriented syntax. The `.` operator only accesses a member of a table as normal, without doing anything special when used in conjunction with a function call, whereas `:` sets the `self` argument of the called function.

Answer (score 2):

`storyboard:addEventLsitener(a,b)` is sugar for `storyboard.addEventLsitener(storyboard,a,b)`.