# Lua: colon notation, 'self' and function definition vs. call

Tags: function, lua, self, notation

I'm getting terribly confused by the colon notation used when defining/calling Lua functions.

I thought I'd got my head round it until I saw this piece of code:

```
function string.PatternSafe( str )
    return ( str:gsub( ".", pattern_escape_replacements ) );
end

function string.Trim( s, char )
    if char then char = char:PatternSafe() else char = "%s" end
    return string.match( s, "^" .. char .. "*(.-)" .. char .. "*$" ) or s
end
```

What's confusing me here is that string.PatternSafe() doesn't reference 'self' anywhere, yet the code seems to work.

I've also seen some scripts that use colon notation when defining the function, for example:

```
function foo:bar( param1 ) ... end
```

After several hours of googling I've still not managed to work out what precisely is happening in these two contexts. My current assumptions are as follows:

1. If a function is defined using colon notation, it gets an invisible 'self' parameter inserted as first parameter
2. If a function is called using colon notation, the object preceding ':' is inserted in to the arguments (so becomes the first parameter of the function)
3. If a function is called using dot notation, then even if it was defined using colon notation it will not get the object inserted as first argument/parameter

If my assumptions are correct, that raises an additional question: What is the best way to ensure that the function was called properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between . and : in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your assumptions are all correct.

Assumption 1 from [the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.9):

> The colon syntax is used for defining methods, that is, functions
>   that have an implicit extra parameter self. Thus, the statement
>
> ```
>  function t.a.b.c:f (params) body end
> ```
>
> is syntactic sugar for
>
> ```
>  t.a.b.c.f = function (self, params) body end
> ```

Assumption 2 from [the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8):

> A call v:name(args) is syntactic sugar for v.name(v,args), except that v is evaluated only once.

Assumption 3 doesn't have a direct manual section since that's just normal function call syntax.

Here's the thing though. `self` is just the auto-magic name given in the syntax sugar used as part of the colon assignment. It isn't a **necessary** name. The first argument is the first argument whatever the name happens to be.

So in your example:

```
function string.PatternSafe( str )
    return ( str:gsub( ".", pattern_escape_replacements ) );
end
```

the first argument is `str` so when the function is called as `char:PatternSafe()` is de-sugars (via assumption 2) to `char.PatternSafe(char)` which is just passing `char` to the function as the first argument (which, as I already said, is `str`).

Comment: What's the best way to determine, from within the called function, whether it was called using dot or colon notation?

Edit: In particular, if called with dot notation by accident, the 'self' will swallow the next parameter (so in foo:bar example, self param would swallow param1 if I called foo.bar("test"), and param1 would be nil).

Comment: You *cannot* tell in the function how you were called. They aren't different. This is all sugar. You *can* tell how many arguments you have and what "types" they are though.

Comment: @Etan Well one possible solution is to check how many arguments were passed. 1 extra? Colon syntax.

Comment: @warspyking Unless the caller just happened to pass you the output from a function that they know produces the output you need and then output you don't care about figuring you'll just ignore the extra input and/or lua will drop it, etc. (i.e. `table.remove(tab, index_from_value(tab, value))` where `index_from_value` returns `ind, val` for convenience). This is why I used to routinely tell people writing C modules not to assert on the value of `lua_gettop` at the start of their functions. But yes, if you don't care about that you can "guess" that way (and I hinted at that with "how many").

Comment: @Etan I've done this with wrappers actually, when wrapping a piece of userdata I'd have to determine if they used dot or colon syntax. I *had* to check that way :P

Comment: @warspyking Right. You can approximate it (especially if your argument type values help) but it is a heuristic at best.