# Lua: addEventListner cannot be nil:nil stack traceback

Tags: lua, null, coronasdk, event-listener, traceback

ok, I've been starring at this error message for better part of a day now.

I'm trying to make a simple eventlistner to run when someone touches a button. The problem is that hower ever I decided to name it it says it's nil and cannot be used.

I'm working on a `scene` with the name "scene", `self.view` named "sceneGroup". The rectangle I try to add a listner to is called "mMnew" and is in the group called "mMnewU".

I've tried to change the name between all of those. At first I hade problem with adding the eventlistener but solved it, problem was not the same sulution worked for the listners name.

Listner:

```
function scene.mMnewUeser:touch(event)  
        if(event.phase == "begun")then
            local test1 = display.newRect(100,150,40,40)
            test1:setFillColor(0,1,0)
            print("Touch found")
        end
    end
```

Added listner:

```
scene:addEventListener("touch", scene.mMnewUeser)
```

I'm still pretty green with this language and used to code in JavaC, php, html, sql and AS3.0. Sorry for my rockie problems!

UPDATE:
After adding a few simple checkpoints check in the code, it would seam that it refuses to run the `function scene:create(event)` my scene does hwoerver get created by `local composer = require("composer")
local scene = composer.newScene()`

Answer (score 0):

This

```
function scene.mMnewUeser:touch(event)
```

is not the correct syntax. You probably meant to have:

```
function scene:mMnewUeser(event)
```

which means you're adding new method with a name **mMnewUeser** to scene object. Then you can just use it as touch listener the way you did in the last line of code. See [an explanation of the difference between . and : here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua).

Comment: Well I tried as you said and removed the :touch part, but it stills says that the listner can't be nil:


`addEventListner:listner cannot be nil: nil stack traceback:

[C]: in function 'error'
?: in function 'gotoScene'
main.lua:18: in main chunk`

Comment: What's on line 18 in main.lua?