# Extracting the last N characters of string in Lua?

Tags: string, lua

I would like to extract the last N characters from a Lua string.

What way I could use to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.sub

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `string.sub` with negative index.

Example

```
string.sub("Hello world", -5) -- => world
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this variant:

```
('Hello world'):sub(-5)  --> world
```

Comment: Does this have any advantage or disadvantage related to the accepted answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4911217/3618581