# lua OOP - how to write Class as a table of tables of functions

Tags: oop, lua

## Context

I'm trying to write a class system which will generate melodies by performing permutations on the notes and rhythms. I'm gonna use this in the tool "xStream" in the "Renoise" software. My example here is a really dumbed down and generic version from what I really have.

I'm also making this as a learning opportunity. My OOP skills are weak, and I still haven't completely wrapped my head around metatables. So a preemptive sorry if I'm totally missing something. I'm doing all my code from the style of the basic OOP examples in the 3rd edition of *Programming in Lua*.

## My question

What I want to do is have class methods with similar functionality all grouped into 'nested' tables. Eg, a table of 'melody permutations', a table of 'rhythm permutations', a table of miscellaneous utility methods, etc.

In the code, I have a class `SomeClass`. It has two types of print functions: `print1_notes` is in the 'main table' (ie, a key of `SomeClass`). `print2.notes` is in a 'nested' table `print2`, which is a key of `SomeClass` (ie, `notes` is just a key of `SomeClass.print2`).

I can call `print1_notes` just fine. The issue is when I call the `print2` methods with the colon operator.
If I don't use sugar (eg, `obj.print2.notes(obj)`), then no problem. But when I do (eg, `obj.print2:notes()`), I get errors about "attempt to (blah blah) a function value ...".

1. How come it works without the colon operator?
2. Do methods in `SomeClass.print2` have access to the keys in `SomeClass`? Do they have access the same way that the non-nested table keys do?
3. I was thinking that `print2` needs an `__index` key to tell its methods to look up the keys in `SomeClass` when it doesn't know what `self.a_key` is. But `self` (inside the `print2` methods) isn't a key. It's really just an alias for `SomeClass`. Is it though? Seems like there's a discrepancy with the nested table.
4. Do I need to make SomeClass the metatable of print2? Is that even possible, since print2 isn't a separate table from SomeClass?
5. Should I try a different approach? Maybe multiple inheritance?

Thanks. Sorry if this needs to be moved or if someone has asked this before.

## My code

```
SomeClass = {
    new = function (self, t)
        t = t or {}
        setmetatable(t, self)
        self.__index = function (_, key)
            return self[key]
        end

        --should I add a setmetatable here? perhaps:
        --setmetatable(self.print2, self)

        return t
    end,


    notes = {},
    set_notes = function (self, t)
        self.notes = t or {}
        self.N = #self.notes
    end,

    print1_notes = function (self)
        print("There are "..tostring(self.N).." notes :", table.unpack(self.notes))
    end,


    --table of different print functions
    print2 = {
        notes = function (self)
            --is self an alias for SomeClass?
            assert(self.notes, "Error: self.notes = nil")
            print("There are "..tostring(self.N).." notes :", table.unpack(self.notes))             
        end,    

        first_note = function (self)
            fn = self.notes[1]
            print("first note is: ", fn)
        end,
    },

}



obj = SomeClass:new()
obj:set_notes{ 10,14,5, 10,14,5, 17 }


print("\ncalling print1_notes without sugar:")
obj.print1_notes(obj)
print("\ncalling print1_notes with sugar:")
obj:print1_notes()
print("\ncalling print2.notes without sugar")
obj.print2.notes(obj)
print("\ncalling print2.notes with sugar")
obj.print2:notes()  --this gives an error: "attempt to get length of a function value"


obj.print2.first_note(obj)  --this works fine
obj.print2:first_note()     --this gives an error: 
                            --  "attempt to index a function value (field 'notes')"
```

EDIT to code: instances of `tostring(N)` needed to be replaced with `tostring(self.N)`.

EDIT: weird errors has to do with the fact that `SomeClass.print2.notes` has a notes member like `SomeClass.notes`. `SomeClass.print2.first_note` avoids this complication. (I'll explain more when I answer)

EDIT: I came up with a solution. It's not pretty, but it works. I'll post my answer below.

Comment: `obj.print2:notes()` is a sugar for `obj.print2.notes(obj.print2)`, not for `obj.print2.notes(obj)`

Comment: Yep. I didn't realize this; the manual wasn't thorough enough on that I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I guess that `Class` has a field `notes` as well, which you try to access in `print2.notes()`

The problem here is that lua doesn't really implement text book object orientation; if you call `class:print_notes(...)` you really just call `class.print_notes(class, ...)`. If you want to call `class.print2.notes(class)` you can't do `class.print2:notes()`, because that is equivalent to calling `class.print2.notes(class.print2)`. Neither can you write `class:print2.notes()` because that's invalid syntax; you can only use `:` to index functions and call them then and there.

EDIT: as for the error you get, `class.print2.notes()` probably tries accessing some `notes` member of `class`, which is probably a table, but because of the colon syntax, instead tries to access `notes()` in `class.print2`, which is a function and results in an error when trying to index it.

As for an actual solution, I'd say you should first of all reconsider the structure of your code. Organizing functions into namespaces inside classes is a somewhat weird approach, and a strong indicator that either your class is bloated and does more than it should, or that it shouldn't really be a class of its own but a library, several classes, or maybe even a simple function.

If either way the two print methods end up printing the notes, and notes is an array, why not extend that array with two print methods? The beauty of luas OO is that there's no clear line between objects and data, and as such it depends on the way you look at it. Try using that strength whenever possible, and don't stick too much to the text books with the OO design, that's not what lua is good at or was ever intended for.

Comment: For more information on how the colon syntax works, I suggest reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua/4911217#4911217

Comment: _"you can't do `class.print2:notes()`, because that is equivalent to calling `class.print2.notes(class.print2)`"._

This is exactly what I was missing. The manual didn't describe the colon syntax for nested tables, so this all makes sense now.

Comment: _"as for the error you get, class.print2.notes() probably tries accessing some notes member of class, which is probably a table, but because of the colon syntax, instead tries to access notes() in class.print2, which is a function and results in an error when trying to index it."_     Yep. Changed `print2.notes` to `print2.thenotes`. Any calls to `self.notes` was replaced with `nil` obviously.

Comment: _"As for an actual solution, I'd say you should first of all reconsider the structure of your code.  ...  your class is bloated and does more than it should, or that it shouldn't really be a class of its own but a library, several classes, or maybe even a simple function."_
Yes, this is definitely true. I said I was planning on writing this big class system, but I really should've said that I'm just in the early stages. I only have this one class right now, and I have plenty of room for new organization schemes in the future. Not to mention, how much I still need to learn in Lua, haha

Comment: Now realizing that `obj = SomeClass:new()` is actually `obj = SomeClass.new(SomeClass)`. This whole time I thought it was instead `obj = SomeClass.new(obj)`. \*facepalm\* This is what I get for copying and pasting code without understanding it.

Comment: So I still want to have the 'namespace' concept. Eg, `SomeClass.print` for any print related functions. I find `obj.print:notes()` more readable than `obj:print_notes()`. Or at the very least, easier on my brain when I'm recalling the members of `SomeClass`. **What do you recommend then, as an alternative?** Let me know if I should just open another post of course.

Comment: Ultimately, I want `SomeClass` to have `SomeClass.notes` and also `SomeClass.delays` which control the timings. I have a group of methods to manipulate the notes, and another distinct group that only manipulates the `delays` member. So it'd be much nicer to call `obj.m_notes:randomize()` or `obj.m_delays:randomize()`. Why would this be a bad idea? I figure I could just use multiple inheritance. `obj` would inherit the members of `m_notes` and `m_delays`. But again, I like the namespace there to remind me which member I'm using, even if they didn't have the same name `randomize()`.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about problem for a while, I noticed there is another approach to solving it and keeping the namespace idea.

Again, you can't use the colon syntax to pass the class to a function that's not in the class, but in a *namespace* of the class. What you **can** however do, is the following:

```
local function print2(instance)
  -- Does things
end

local function wrapper(namespace)
  print2(namespace.instance)
end

function someClass.new()
  ...
  notes = {print=wrapper,instance=t} -- every instance needs its own namespace table
  ...
end
```

as you can see, every instance has its own namespace table, but they all have a reference to the same shared function and a reference to the instance they belong to. When you call `instance.notes:print()` it ends up calling `print` on `instance.notes`, but the function only calls the *real* function on `instance.notes.instance`, which points back to `instance`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution of sorts. In short: any functions in `print2` must start with `self = getmetatable(self)`. This is to turn `self` (originally `obj.print2`) into `obj`.

Also, sorry if this answer is too long or violates any guidelines.

To reiterate, I'm wanting to have another table `SomeClass.print2` which has all print related functions. If I wanted to print the notes, I would do

```
obj.print2:notes()
--sugar for
obj.print2.notes(obj.print2)
```

Of course, when I do this, `self.notes` inside `SomeClass.print2.notes` would refer to `obj.print2.notes` (and not `obj.notes`). This is an issue even if I rename the function to  `SomeClass.print2.the_notes`.

## New Code

So what I did is changed `SomeClass:new` into this:

```
SomeClass:new = function (self, t)
    t = t or {}                     -- 
    setmetatable(t, self)           --
    self.__index = function (_, k)  --
        return self[k]              --
    end                             -- same from before

    mt = {}
    mt.print2 = {}
    mt.print2.__index = SomeClass.print2  -- only fixes calls to obj.print2:foo()

    t.print2 = {}
    setmetatable( t.print2, mt.print2)
    setmetatable(mt.print2, t)
    t.__index = t  -- fixes references to self.key inside print2 functions

    return t
end
```

And `SomeClass.print2` should look like this now:

```
SomeClass.print2 = {
    notes = function (self)
        self = getmetatable(self)   -- self is now mt.print2
                                    -- self.notes will become obj.notes
        self = getmetatable(self)   -- self should just be obj now
                                    -- but this is unnecessary

        print("There are "..tostring(self.N).." notes :", table.unpack(self.notes))             
    end,    

    first_note = function (self)
        self = getmetatable(self)

        fn = self.notes[1]
        print("first note is: ", fn)
    end,
}
```

So basically, any calls to `obj.print2.foo` should return `SomeClass.print2.foo`. (See `mt.print2.__index`).

Every function in `SomeClass.print2` MUST have at least one '`self = getmetatable(self)`' at the top of the function body**. Then, inside `SomeClass.print2.foo()`, `self` is `mt.print2`. So then, `self.key` should become:

- `obj.key` if `key` is `notes` or `N`
- if `obj.key` is nil, then become `SomeClass.key` instead

** A second `self = getmetatable(self)` is recommended, but optional.

## Very detailed explanation

Step-by-step, what we have is

1. Create a new object with `obj = SomeClass:new()`

   - `obj` has an empty table at `obj.print2`
   - A new table `mt` is created, which is associated with `obj`
   - more specifically, `mt.print2` is the metatable of `obj.print2`, and the metatable of `mt.print2` is obj
2. Set notes (eg, `obj:set_notes{10,20,30}`)
3. call `obj.print2:notes()`, ie, `obj.print2.notes(obj.print2)`

   - obj.print2.somekey is nil where '`somekey`' is `notes`
   - So we look for the `__index` function in the metatable of `obj.print2`
   - `mt.__index` returns `SomeClass.print2.somekey`
   - So `obj.print2.notes(obj.print2)` is now `SomeClass.print2.notes(obj.print2)`
4. Inside the call (part 1)

   - `self` is `obj.print2`
   - we want to get `obj.notes` using `self.notes`
   - So we change `self` into its metatable once. We do `self = getmetatable(self)`.
   - `self` is now `mt.print2`
   - Now, if we did `self.notes`, this will be `mt.print2.notes`

     - `mt.print2.notes` is nil
     - This will call `obj.__index` because `obj` is the metatable for `mt.print2`
     - So `mt.print2.notes` should become `obj.notes`
     - Therefore, `self.notes` becomes `obj.notes`
5. Inside the call (part 2)

   - `self` is `mt.print2`
   - We could do `self = getmetatable(self)` again
   - Then `self` would just become `obj`, since that's the metatable for `mt.print2`

## Notes

This is a pretty ugly solution, I'll admit. But it works.

I hate having to put `self = getmetatable(self)` at the top of any function body in `SomeClass.print2`. This could be avoided if there was someway to transform `self` into `obj` inside of `mt.print2.__index`. I'm pretty sure that's impossible, since `mt.print2.__index` can only return an object (ie, the function `SomeClass.print2.foo`).

The reason I made `mt` a table with `mt.print2` was so that I could add more of these 'namespaced' functions to `SomeClass`. If I wanted a namespace `m_notes` for functions that transform the notes, I would just add these statements to `SomeClass:new()`:

```
mt.m_notes = {}
mt.m_notes.__index = SomeClass.m_notes

t.m_notes = {}
setmetatable( t.m_notes, mt.m_notes )
setmetatable(mt.m_notes, t)
```

In fact, I could make a function that does this for any new namespace:

```
add_namespace = function( t, mt, key_string )
    mt[key_string] = {}
    mt[key_string].__index = SomeClass[key_string]
     t[key_string] = {}
    setmetatable( t[key_string], mt[key_string] )
    setmetatable(mt[key_string], t)
end
```

Maybe it'd be better to make `mt` just be a member in `t`. So `mt` would just be `t.mt` and `mt.print2` would be `t.mt.print2`, etc. Then it could be accessed later if needed (eg, for encapsulation purposes). There aren't any issues with having `mt` by itself; Calling `SomeClass:new()` will always create a new `mt` to be associated with the new object.

Please comment if you can think of any performace issues/enhancements with this trick. Or if I can make it more elegant looking. Definitely let me know if you can think of any way to remove the `self = getmetatable(self)` at the top of every `print2` function definition.