# implementing __index metafunction in C/c++

Tags: c++, lua, callback, meta-method

I have a script to C++ callback/functor system that can call any "registered" C++ function using strings and/or variants.

```
//REMOVED ERROR CHECKS AND ERRONEOUS STUFF FOR THIS POST
int LuaGameObject::LuaCallFunction( lua_State *luaState )
{
    if ( lua_isuserdata( luaState, 1 ) == 1 )
    {
        int nArgs = lua_gettop( luaState );

        //Get GameObject
        OGameObject* pGameObject = static_cast<OGameObject*>(lua_touserdata( luaState, 1 ));
        if ( pGameObject )
        {
            //Get FunctionName
            const char* functionNameString = lua_tostring( luaState, 2 );

            //Get Args
            std::vector<OVariant> args;
            for ( int i = 3; i <= nArgs; ++i )
            {
                OVariant variant;
                variant.SetFromLua( luaState, i );
                args.push_back( variant );
            }

            //Call it!
            CallGameObjectFunction( luaState, pGameObject, functionNameString, args );

            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

OVariant LuaGameObject::ExecuteLua()
{
    lua_State *lState = luaL_newstate();

    luaL_openlibs( lState );
    lua_register( lState, "Call", LuaCallFunction );

    luaL_loadstring( lState, m_pScript );

    //now run it
    lua_pcall( lState, 0, 1, 0 );

    //process return values
    OVariant result;
    result.SetFromLua( lState, -1 );

    lua_close( lState );

    return result;
}
```

In lua I can do something like this...

```
local king = Call("EmpireManager","GetKing")
Call("MapCamera","ZoomToActor",king)
```

However, I am feeling that I can use the __index metamethod to simplify the lua...

```
local king = EmpireManager:GetKing()
MapCamera:ZoomToActor(king)
```

I was hoping to achieve the simplified lua by using the following implemenation of the __index metamethod

Here is how I register the __index metafunction... (mostly copied from online examples)

```
void LuaGameObject::Register( lua_State * l )
{
    luaL_Reg sRegs[] =
    {
        { "__index", &LuaGameObject::LuaCallFunction },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

    luaL_newmetatable( l, "luaL_EmpireManager" );

    // Register the C functions into the metatable we just created.
    luaL_setfuncs( l, sRegs, 0 );
    lua_pushvalue( l, -1 );

    // Set the "__index" field of the metatable to point to itself
    // This pops the stack
    lua_setfield( l, -1, "__index" );

    // Now we use setglobal to officially expose the luaL_EmpireManager metatable 
    // to Lua. And we use the name "EmpireManager".
    lua_setglobal( l, "EmpireManager" );
}
```

Unfortunately, I cant seem to get the callback setup right.  Lua correctly calls my LuaGameObject::LuaCallFunction, but the stack does not contain what I would like.  From within the LuaGameObject::LuaCallFunction,  I can find the function name and EmpireManager object on the stack. But, I cant find the args on the stack.  What is the proper way to set this up?  Or is it not possible?

Comment: Part of your issue is that the scope resolution operator, `::`, is not part of the C language and there is no C/C++ language.  I recommend switching to the C++ language only and not worrying about C.

Comment: I suppose that what you want to do is use colon syntax in Lua script: `MapCamera:ZoomToActor(king)`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua

Comment: tx guys for the quick response!  I am using c++.  I have edited the post to reduce confusion.  Remember, my LuaGameObject::LuaCallFunction is called from lua when it gets to local king = EmpireManager.GetKing().  But i'm not sure how to retrieve the args. (maybe its not possible?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to add methods to a `userdata` type in Lua, as explained in the [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.3.html) guide from the official website.

When you type the following Lua code:

```
myUserdata:someMethod(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

Assuming `myUserdata` is a "userdata" object, the interpreter will do the following.

1. Call `getmetatable(myUserdata).__index(myUserdata,"someMethod")` to get the value of `someMethod`.
2. Call `someMethod(myUserdata,arg1,arg2,arg3)`. `someMethod` can be anything callable from Lua. Examples: a Lua or C function, or a table/userdata with a `__call` metamethod.

Your `__index` metamethod should just return a function (or another object callable from Lua) implementing the method. Something like this:

```
// IMO, quite a misleading name for the __index metamethod (there is a __call metamethod)
int LuaGameObject::LuaCallFunction( lua_State *l)
{
    // todo: error checking
    OGameObject* pGameObject = static_cast<OGameObject*>(lua_touserdata( luaState, 1 ));
    std::string memberName = lua_tostring( luaState, 2 );

    int result = 1;
    if (memberName == "method1") {
        lua_pushcfunction(l,LuaGameObject::luaMethod1);
    } else if (memberName == "method2") {
        lua_pushcfunction(l,LuaGameObject::luaMethod2);
    } else {
        result = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Basic skeleton of the functions returned by the `__index` metamethod:

```
int LuaGameObject::luaMethod1(lua_State* l) {
    // todo: error checking.
    OGameObject* pGameObject = static_cast<OGameObject*>(lua_touserdata(l, 1));
    float arg1 = lua_tonumber(l, 2);
    // get other args
    pGameObject->method1(arg1 /*, more args if any.*/);
    // optionally push return values on the stack.
    return 0; // <-- number of return values.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after more research,  I now believe that I cannot use __index metafunction to call a c functor with arguments.  It only passes the table name and the key to the callback.

However, for anyone interested, it can be used for table-like objects, but not functions (as arguments are not pushed onto the stack).  I will it for my "property" objects.  They have no arguments and can be used in lua as follows...

```
local king = EmpireManager:king
king:name = "Arthur"
local name = king:name
```

These properly link to and call the appropriate C++ objects.functions

```
Actor::SetName(std::string name)
std::string Actor::GetName()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to call a method from my object and have used this post to develop the solution.

I hope that the example below can be useful to you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

extern "C" {
#include "lua/lua.h"
#include "lua/lauxlib.h"
#include "lua/lualib.h"
}

//template<class UserdataType>          // if will be work with lua garbage collector, use a function like that to delete the this_ptr (1st param)
//int DeletePtr(lua_State *lua_state) { // It's necessary register the metatable.__gc and to trust in gc (create just pointer of LuaObjects
//  UserdataType** this_ptr = reinterpret_cast<UserdataType**>(lua_touserdata(lua_state, 1));
//  delete (*this_ptr);
//  return 0;
//}

template<class UserdataType>
int Closure(lua_State *lua_state) {
  UserdataType** ptr = reinterpret_cast<UserdataType**>(lua_touserdata(lua_state, 1)); // This closure is being called by call operator ()
  return (*ptr)->CallFunction(lua_state);                                              // To access the function name called use lua stack index with lua_upvalueindex(-1)
}                                                                                      // Call the object method to resolve this called there

template<class UserdataType>
int ReturnClosure(lua_State *lua_state) {                // This function is called as a lookup of metatable.__index
  lua_pushcclosure(lua_state, Closure<UserdataType>, 1); // then we will return a closure to be called through call operator ()
  return 1;                                              // The 1st param (the only one) is the action name of function
}                                                        // Then a closure will grant access to ReturnClosure params as upvalues (lua_upvalueindex)

class LuaObject {
public:
  LuaObject() :  userdata_name("userdata1") {
  } 

  void CreateNewUserData(lua_State* lua_ptr, const std::string& global_name) {
    RegisterUserData(lua_ptr);
    LuaObject** this_ptr = reinterpret_cast<LuaObject**>(lua_newuserdata(lua_ptr, sizeof(LuaObject*)));
    *this_ptr = this;
    luaL_getmetatable(lua_ptr, userdata_name.c_str()); 
    lua_setmetatable(lua_ptr, -2);                        // setmetatable(this_ptr, userdata_name)
    lua_setglobal(lua_ptr, global_name.c_str());          // store to global scope
  }

  int CallFunction(lua_State* lua_state) const {
    std::string name = lua_tostring(lua_state, lua_upvalueindex(1)); // userdata:<function>(param2, param3)
    auto it = functions.find(name);                                  // <function> lua_tostring(lua_state, lua_upvalueindex(1))
    if (it != functions.end()) {                                     // <implicit this> lua_touserdata(l, 1)
      return it->second(lua_state);                                  // <param #1> lua_touserdata(l, 2)
    }                                                                // <param #2> lua_touserdata(l, 3)
    return 0;                                                        // <param #n> lua_touserdata(l, n+1)
  }

  void NewFunction(const std::string& name, std::function<int(lua_State*)> func) {
    functions[name] = func;
  }
private:
  void RegisterUserData(lua_State* lua_ptr) {
    luaL_getmetatable(lua_ptr, userdata_name.c_str());
    if (lua_type(lua_ptr, -1) == LUA_TNIL) {
      /* create metatable for userdata_name */
      luaL_newmetatable(lua_ptr, userdata_name.c_str());
      lua_pushvalue(lua_ptr, -1); /* push metatable */
 
      /* metatable.__gc = DeletePtr<LuaObject> */
      //lua_pushcfunction(lua_ptr, DeletePtr<LuaObject>);
      //lua_setfield(lua_ptr, -2, "__gc");

      /* metatable.__index = ReturnClosure<LuaObject> */
      lua_pushcfunction(lua_ptr, ReturnClosure<LuaObject>);
      lua_setfield(lua_ptr, -2, "__index");
    }
  }
  std::map<std::string, std::function<int(lua_State*)>> functions;
  std::string userdata_name;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  lua_State* lua_state = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(lua_state);
    
  LuaObject luaobj;
  luaobj.CreateNewUserData(lua_state, "test_obj");
  luaobj.NewFunction("action", [](lua_State* l)->int {
    std::string result = "action has been executed";
    LuaObject** ptr = reinterpret_cast<LuaObject**>(lua_touserdata(l, 1));
    result += "\n #1 param is user_data (self == this) value = " + std::to_string(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(*ptr));     
    for (int i = 2; i <= lua_gettop(l); ++i) {
      result += "\n #" + std::to_string(i)+ " = " + lua_tostring(l, i);
    }
    result += "\n #n param is passed on call operator () #n = " + std::to_string(lua_gettop(l));
    lua_pushfstring(l, result.c_str());
    return 1;
  });

  std::string lua_code;    
  lua_code += "print(test_obj:unknown_function()) \n";  
  lua_code += "print(test_obj:action())           \n";
  lua_code += "print(test_obj:action(1))          \n";
  lua_code += "print(test_obj:action(1, 2))       \n";
  lua_code += "print(test_obj:action(1, 2, 'abc'))\n";

  if (!(luaL_loadbuffer(lua_state, lua_code.c_str(), lua_code.length(), NULL) == 0 && lua_pcall(lua_state, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0) == 0)) {
      std::cerr << "Lua Code Fail: " << lua_tostring(lua_state, -1) << std::endl;        
  }  
  lua_close(lua_state);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
action has been executed
 #1 param is user_data (self == this) value = 13629232
 #n param is passed on call operator () #n = 1
action has been executed
 #1 param is user_data (self == this) value = 13629232
 #2 = 1
 #n param is passed on call operator () #n = 2
action has been executed
 #1 param is user_data (self == this) value = 13629232
 #2 = 1
 #3 = 2
 #n param is passed on call operator () #n = 3
action has been executed
 #1 param is user_data (self == this) value = 13629232
 #2 = 1
 #3 = 2
 #4 = abc
 #n param is passed on call operator () #n = 4
```