# __tostring in custom classes Lua

Tags: lua, tostring, metatable

The following code should print 'hello', however it is printing the memory location of the table (i.e. 'table: 052E67D0'). Please, explain what I'm missing here.

```lua
TestClass = {}

function TestClass:new(o) 
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end

function TestClass:__tostring()
    return "hello"
end

local t = TestClass.new{}

print(t)
```

### **Update**

Tried doing this instead:

```lua
TestClass = {}

function TestClass:new(o) 
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    self.__tostring = function() return "hello" end
    return o
end
local t = TestClass.new{}

print(t)
```

which worked. This seems weird because, to me, `self` in constructor and `TestClass:` refer to the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TestClass:new` takes two arguments and you call it with just one when you create `t`.

Change:

```
local t = TestClass.new{}
```

to:

```
local t = TestClass:new{}
```

Thanks to that `self` in this `TestClass:new` call is now reference to `TestClass` rather than to empty table which was (most likely) meant to be the new instance of the class.

In case of doubts please refer to [Lua Reference Manual §3.4.10](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10) or [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua).