# Editing a subtable inside a maintable using a function inside the maintable

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is it possible to edit the contents of a table which is inside another table using a function?

```
local MainTable = {
  subtable = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0
 }, 

 addX = function() 
  subtable.x = subtable.x + 1
 end
}
```

I'm getting the error attempt to index ? (a nil value)
Is it possible to achieve this?
It works outside the table, I used:

```
print(MainTable.subtable.x+1)
```

How come it doesn't work inside the table? Does tables being objects play a role?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't valid syntax. It's not clear what you want `Maintable` and `subtable` to be, with `{` right after them. [Try it on tio.run](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Jz85MUfBNzEzryQxKSdVoZpLQaG4NAnBUVCoULBVMNABMytBTC6FWi4uhcSUlAggL600L7kkMz9PQ1MBSaceSA8SR1vBkEshNS@Fq/b/fwA)

Comment: @aschepler, it is not, you're right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua tables aren't objects; just because you're declaring `addX` inside `MainTable`, it is not aware of anything else inseide `MainTable`.

One solution would be:

```lua
local MainTable
MainTable = {
...
   addX = function()
      MainTable.subtable.x = MainTable.subtable.x + 1
   end
}
```

but a better way would be

```lua
local MainTable = {
   subtable = {
      x = 0,
      y = 0
   }
}

function MainTable:addX() 
   self.subtable.x = self.subtable.x + 1
end

-- Use it as:
MainTable:addX()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was trying to use the table as class, since I normally program in Java. I was hoping I could use the subtable inside the class using a method, just like in Java. So I like the first solution better, why is the second one better? And Is self a thing in LUA? Like this. in Java?

Comment: `self` is not its own thing in Lua; it's really just another function argument, but calling a function in a table with `tab:func(foo)` is the same as calling it as `tab.func(tab, foo)` which makes it "look" like a method call. In most real-world cases, you don't even notice the difference. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua)'s some more info on this :D

Comment: I think I understood. Do I have to declare self as a function argument or is it being replace automatically with Maintable when I call the function as Maintable:addX()?

Comment: If you define the function as `function tab:func(foo)` it works the same way; it gets turned into `function tab.func(self, foo)` so you can use `self` inside the function.