# kong cache invalidation throws error : key must be a string

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin

In a custom plugin I need to invalidate a Kong cache entry.
When I use

```
kong.cache.invalidate_local("thisisastring")
```

I get error

```
key must be a string
 stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cache/init.lua:226: in function 'invalidate_local'
```

I'm using Kong 2.7.0.

https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/2.7.0/kong/cache/init.lua#L226

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `:` not `.`

```
      kong.cache:invalidate_local("your string")
```

More info about [difference between : and .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua)

Comment: oops,  my bad :-( . Thx !