# Lua table.insert() is overwriting all indices in my table

Tags: lua

The `table.insert()` function is overwriting all indices in my table. I am trying to append tokens to the table to pass on to a parser, but it isn't working. Here are some code snippets:

Tokenizing, where the problem is happening:

```lua
function Lexer:Tokenize()
  local Tokens = {}

  while self.CC ~= nil do
    if string.find(" \t", self.CC) then
      self:Advance()

    -- Numbers
    elseif string.find(C.DIGITS, self.CC) then
      table.insert(Tokens, self:MakeNumber())

    -- Operators
    elseif self.CC == "+" then
      table.insert(Tokens, TOK:new(C.TT_PLUS, nil, self.Pos))
      self:Advance()
    elseif self.CC == "-" then
      table.insert(Tokens, TOK:new(C.TT_MINUS, nil, self.Pos))
      self:Advance()
    elseif self.CC == "*" then
      table.insert(Tokens, TOK:new(C.TT_MUL, nil, self.Pos))
      self:Advance()
    elseif self.CC == "/" then
      table.insert(Tokens, TOK:new(C.TT_DIV, nil, self.Pos))
      self:Advance()
    elseif self.CC == "(" then
      table.insert(Tokens, TOK:new(C.TT_LPAREN, nil, self.Pos))
      self:Advance()
    elseif self.CC == ")" then
      table.insert(Tokens, TOK:new(C.TT_RPAREN, nil, self.Pos))
      self:Advance()

    -- Errors
    else
      local PosStart = self.Pos:Copy()
      local Char = self.CC
      self:Advance()
      return {}, E.IllegalCharError:new(string.format("'%s'",Char, PosStart, self.Pos))
    end
  end

  for k, v in pairs(Tokens) do
    print(k, v:repr())
  end

  table.insert(Tokens, TOK:new(C.TT_EOF, nil, self.Pos))
  return Tokens, nil
end
```

And here is the code for the token class. Token:repr() is just a way to make the string look nice.

```lua
local C = require("constants")

local Token = {
  Type = "",
  Value = nil,
  PosStart = nil,
  PosEnd = nil
}

-- Token initializer
function Token:new(Type, Value, PosStart, PosEnd)
  Value = Value or nil
  PosStart = PosStart or nil
  PosEnd = PosEnd or nil
  setmetatable({}, Token)

  self.Type = Type
  self.Value = Value
  if PosStart then
    self.PosStart = PosStart:Copy()
    self.PosEnd = PosStart:Copy()
  end
  if PosEnd then
    self.PosEnd = PosEnd:Copy()
  end

  return self
end

function Token:repr()
  if self.Value ~= nil then
    return string.format("%s: %s", self.Type, self.Value)
  end
  return string.format("%s", self.Type)
end

return Token
```

Help appreciated :)

Comment: Forgot to mention that, when I input "1 + 2" into this, the output is:
1   integer: 2
2   integer: 2
3   integer: 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your `Token` constructor:

```lua
-- Token initializer
function Token:new(Type, Value, PosStart, PosEnd)
  Value = Value or nil
  PosStart = PosStart or nil
  PosEnd = PosEnd or nil
  setmetatable({}, Token)

  self.Type = Type
  self.Value = Value
  if PosStart then
    self.PosStart = PosStart:Copy()
    self.PosEnd = PosStart:Copy()
  end
  if PosEnd then
    self.PosEnd = PosEnd:Copy()
  end

  return self
end
```

You're assigning to `self`, but what is `self` here when you call this constructor as [`Token:new(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua)? It is the "class table" `Token`. The line `setmetatable({}, Token)` has no effect; the newly created table is discarded immediately after since you're not assigning it to any variable.

Your constructor does not require passing `Token` since you already have & use `Token` as an upvalue. If you're not interested in having further classes inherit from `Token`, and since you're trying to keep the constructor simple, I'd recommend simply getting rid of the unnecessary `self` argument (you were probably copying some Lua OOP pattern, where this is used to allow implementing inheritance later on):

```lua
function Token.new(Type, Value, PosStart, PosEnd)
```

note the `.` instead of `:` to not add an implicit `self` argument. You'll also have to change your calls from `TOK:new(...)` to just `TOK.new(...)` (notice again swapping `:` for `.` since there is no need to pass the token class to one of its functions).

`self` has to be the newly created instance:

```lua
local self = setmetatable({}, Token)
```

everything should work if you make these changes. `table.insert` is not the culprit here.

Comment: So, for the :repr() method, what I want to do is .repr() instead, and you pass in the new object, right?

Comment: I tested it, and it works. Thanks so much! I don't use OOP that much in Lua.

Comment: @TheTrueBear don't worry, your `repr` method is all fine and idiomatic. My points only apply to the constructor; methods *need* a `self` instance variable passed.