# How does parameter for functions work in lua?

Tags: lua, love2d

So I got this chunk of code that for some reason is giving me a null exception on LOVE

```
function enemies_controller:spawnEnemy(x, y, rad)
enemy = {}
enemy.x = x
enemy.y = y
enemy.rad = rad
enemy.speedMulti = 1
table.insert(enemies_controller.enemies, enemy)
end
```

And the function calling it like this:

```
enemies_controller.spawnEnemy(100, 100, 50)
```

The thing is that is giving me a null exception on the enemy.rad when i draw, cause enemy.x takes the second function parameter and enemy.y the third, and none takes the first one... So i am unsure of what is happening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between . and : in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua)

Answer (score 5):

It's because using `:` creates a "self" parameter. (This is a typing shortcut because lots of people make functions with self parameters. It doesn't do anything special.)

```
function enemies_controller:spawnEnemy(x, y, rad)
```

is the same as

```
function enemies_controller.spawnEnemy(self, x, y, rad)
```

or in other words:

```
enemies_controller.spawnEnemy = function(self, x, y, rad)
```

Notice the difference between `.` and `:`.

A similar thing when you call it:

```
enemies_controller:spawnEnemy(100, 100, 50)
```

is the same as:

```
enemies_controller.spawnEnemy(enemies_controller, 100, 100, 50)
```

and the first one is probably how you're meant to call the function - there's no other reason they'd define it with `:`.

If you call

```
enemies_controller.spawnEnemy(100, 100, 50)
```

then you pass 100 as `self`, 100 as `x` and 50 as `y` and nil as `rad`