# Class Function returns wrong values - Lua

Tags: class, vector, lua, 3d

I make program in lua where I create a class that stores 3 values and a function that can return the "x" value. This is the code:

```
Vector3 = {}
Vector3.__index = Vector3

function Vector3:new(x,y,z)
  local instance = 
  {
    x = x or 0,
    y = y or 0,
    z = z or 0
  }
  setmetatable(instance, Vector3)
  return instance
end

function Vector3:printX()
  return self.x
end
```

And this is my main.lua code:

```
require "Vector3"

vec1 = Vector3.new(1,2,3)
vec2 = Vector3.new(5,1,0)

print(vec1:printX())
```

This what this line does

```
vec1 = Vector3.new(1,2,3)
```

Is create a new class and assign 1 to x, 2 to y, and 3 to z. But when I print out the value returned by printX(), it gives me 2. If I change it to print out the y value, it gives me 3. And if I change it to print out the z value, its nil. Is there anything wrong with my code?

I want it to return the correct values.

Comment: `function Vector3:new(` means the first parameter of your constructor is `self` which you seemingly did not intend. You can just declare `Vector3.new`.

Comment: @tehtmi What if I wanna assign variables when creating it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you aren't using the `self` parameter. You don't need `:` to create the instance and return it as you are doing. You could alternative call `new` as `Vector3:new` to pass `Vector3` as the self parameter, but this is also unnecessary.

Comment: Crap. I'm dumb. I didn't realize that in your first comment you had a "." instead of a ":". Thanks that helped @tehtmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tehtmi has pointed out, `function Vector3:new(x,y,z)` is equivalent to `function Vector3.new(self,x,y,z)`. The call `Vector3.new(1,2,3)` thus sets `self = 1`, `x = 2`, `y = 3` and `z = nil`; `2` is printed.

There are two ways to fix this:

- Fix your constructor to be simply `Vector3.new`, removing the `self` parameter.
- Fix your call to be `Vector3:new`, passing `self = Vector3`. This obsoletes the `Vector3` global variable access in the constructor; `setmetatable(instance, Vector3)` can then be replaced with `setmetatable(instance, self)`.

If you rewrite the constructor slightly, you get the [standard "class" template outlined in the "Programming in Lua" book](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html):

```lua
function Vector3:new(x,y,z)
  local instance = 
  {
    x = x or 0,
    y = y or 0,
    z = z or 0
  }
  setmetatable(instance, self)
  self.__index = self -- note the addition of this line
  return instance
end
```

You can then remove the `Vector3.__index = Vector3` line since this will be done in the constructor every time you call `Vector3:new(...)` (arguably questionable performance-wise). The advantage of this approach is [how it deals with inheritance](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html): Inheritance is implemented simply as instantiation; you do not need to take care of writing a new constructor. Say you want a class `Scale` to extend your `Vector3` class:

```lua
Scale = Vector3:new() -- a scale is a vector ("inherits")
function Scale:scale(vec) -- scale a vector (componentwise multiplication)
    return Vector3:new(self.x * vec.x, self.y * vec.y, self.z * vec.z)
end
```

Usage:

```
-- Instantiation:
-- This wouldn't work if you used `.`
-- since then `Scale.new` would be just `Vector3.new`
-- which sets `Vector3` and not `Scale` as the metatable,
-- but since the `:` passes `Scale`/`Vector3` as `self`, everything is fine.
local s = Scale:new(1, 2, 3)
local v = s:scale(Vector3.new(4, 5, 6))
print(v.x, v.y, v.z) -- 4, 10, 18
```

You ultimately have to decide whether you prefer constructors looking up their class through an upvalue or global variable or having it passed as the `self` parameter.

As a rule of thumb, if you define a function using `:`, you should probably call it using `:`. Such functions are often called "methods". See [difference between `.` and `:` in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua).

---

Besides, I would rename `printX` to `getX` or remove it entirely (since it is currently redundant with just directly accessing `x`).
Note also that default values are often implemented by sticking them into the class table (in your case `Vector3.x, Vector3.y, Vector3.z = 0, 0, 0` would allow you to eliminate the `or 0`'s in the constructor).

Comment: Thank you for this in depth explanation. I now understand this better.